# Проблема с центрированием Canvas в jsPDF

Tags: javascript, vue.js

проект использует:

- Vue js
- konva js lib
- jsPDF lib

Суть проекта заключается в создание специальных логотипов с помощью канваса и вью, которые должны сохраняться в пдф(15 размеров) при этом скейлиться до нужных размер и центрироваться по вертикали и горизонтали

Сейчас я делаю scale канваса и после беру картинку как dataUri
если создать картинку и загнать dataUri что бы получить размеры, мы получаем неадекватные размеры по типу 3600 х 9000
при этом картинка адекватно отображается при сохранение в пдф размером 1800х2700

На логотипах есть отключаемые элементы которые так же должны влиять на позиционирование

с канвасом работаю недолго, может есть решение которое позволит получать реальные размеры логотипа

P.S. сам логотип черный а фон белый

Comment: то что Вы делает - называется cropper. https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/ - я думаю, что здесь Вы сможете найти пример для любого Вашего метода

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#image-manipulation здесь можете взять готовые решения